# CKEditor inline editing - content isnt editable?

Tags: ckeditor

I downloaded the latest CKEditor and tried the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor">
Some test text
</div>
<script>
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor' );
</script>
</body>
```

It worked in the sense that I can click the div to make the editor toolbar appear, but aside from that I can't seem to edit the content! Most of the toolbar buttons are disabled, and typing into the field does nothing. (See screenshot below)

[image]

According to http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-04-14-07-42/standard/samples/inlinebycode.html this should be all the JS I need. Is there some other config setting I need to be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rawr, sorry. I found the answer mere minutes after posting this. I was so focused on looking for a config option I didn't realize to check the div in the example.

The div still has to have `contenteditable="true"` even if I don't use `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline`.